# Looking for a script/method of playing mp4s in an old TV on a website

Tags: video, video-streaming, flowplayer, television

I'd like to have mp4s playing on a webpage inside an old TV, and I am wondering if there is a script, or a combination of scripts that would give me this effect.  The ability to have buttons on the TV that actually start the movie/control the volume etc. would be a bonus, as would the odd old-time visual effect (poor signal, lines in image, etc., but without having to alter the actual MP4), as well as the ability to warp the video image so that it fits the curved screen.  I'd also like the option to go fullscreen, as with flowplayer.

I think I saw a method of doing something like this a while back, but from googling about today, I haven't turned up much.

So far I just have flowplayer installed on the webpage, and an image of an old TV with a cut out where the movie would show.  But I can't work out how to get the image showing above the flowplayer block.  I have tried using z-index, but to no avail.

Any advice to get me further down the road would be gratefully received.

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to mash together a couple of the demos to achieve the effect you are looking for.

Here's the demo for changing the video container to a billboard: http://flowplayer.org/demos/skinning/container-background.html

I'm not sure if you could attach javascript callbacks the controls in your TV image using the container method, if you can't you probably want to overlay flowplayer on a div holding your TV image and use javascript there.  To do this I would start with the z-index demo: http://flowplayer.org/demos/configuration/wmode.html